# How to show search address on google map.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

> I am working on goole map and i add the following for search bar on google map and get the coordinates of particular search address. Now i want to show it on map also after selection on place. Please look at my code.

-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

```
GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
// Do something with the selected place.
NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);

CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude);
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coordinates zoom:10];
[_mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];






[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }

 - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
 didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
// TODO: handle the error.
NSLog(@"error: %ld", (long)[error code]);
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

   // User canceled the operation.
 - (void)wasCancelled:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController {
NSLog(@"Autocomplete was cancelled.");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

> How will i update lat and long on map?

Comment: GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coordinate zoom:15];
        [mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];

Comment: In place of coordinate pass your coordinates. And mapView_ is type of GMSMapView

Comment: should i passed is on didupdatelocaiton method?

Comment: you can paste those two lines of code in - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
 didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place method and in the place of coordinate you can pass place.coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude,place.coordinate.longitude);
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coordinates zoom:10];
 [yourmapViewName animateWithCameraUpdate:cameraUpdate];
```

**Update Answer**

```
 - (void)viewController:(GMSAutocompleteViewController *)viewController
 didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
// Do something with the selected place.
NSLog(@"Place name %@", place.name);
NSLog(@"Place address %@", place.formattedAddress);
NSLog(@"Place attributions %@", place.attributions.string);
NSLog(@"lat and log%f", place.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"lang %f", place.coordinate.longitude);


 CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude,place.coordinate.longitude);
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:coordinates zoom:10];
 [yourmapViewName animateWithCameraUpdate:cameraUpdate];


 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: sir is that CLLocationCoordinate2D compatible in this method? because i get this error initializing  CLLocationCoordinate2D with expression of incompatible type CLLocationCoordinate2D

Comment: if use these line of code it give me strange behavior on map, it will change the camera position on map    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:place.coordinate.longitude longitude:place.coordinate.latitude zoom:14];
    
    [_mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

Comment: initializing CLLocationCoordinate2D with expression of incompatible type CLLocationCoordinate2D

Comment: but when is use two line of code which i mention in comment than i am not get any error but not able to update lat long on google map

Comment: @sandeeptomar - change this `CLLocationCoordinate2D  *coordinates` into `CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinates` and try once

Comment: yes sir its working fine but i have one issue here, i want show my current location and search location both on map?

Comment: Please give some suggestion for this task so i move forward. Thanks in advance bro